How to set a distinct label for each plotted curve?

In [9]: %matplotlib qt
   ...: from sympy import *
   ...: 
   ...: x = symbols('x')
   ...: plot(4-x**3/2, x*x, (x, 0, 2), legend=1)


As you can see, I can plot two curves and Sympy takes care of labelling them, but.
I want to label the first curve "cubic" and the second one "quadratic", but I don't kmow how to specify two labels, I tried with label=['c', 'q'] but Sympy displayed "['c', 'q']" twice…
How can I set a distinct label for each curve?

Did you look into Python SymPy's plotting legend when using multiple ranges and How can I manually specify text for legends in sympy.plotting.plot??

@JohanC I googled a little bit before posting, but those posts didn't hit my attention… I'll have a look asap, Thank you very much.

@JohanC The first answer can be adapted to my use case. Oh you Python gold badge, could you please close my question? Thank you again.
